# vuejs 3: declare an emit event in a child component via emits option

Tags: javascript, components, vuejs3

Using Vue 3.2 and I'm under the impression that I follow the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html)

I'm sending an array of objects to a child component and in return, I am trying to emit an event to the parent compenent so one object (identified by id) gets deleted from the array.

```js
// parent
<template>
    <TheAccountLines :lines=recurrents_credits @goaway(id)="goaway(id)" />
</template>

<script setup>
import { find } from "lodash"
// this doesn't get called at all, just putting it here to show that the function exists.
const goaway = (id) => {
  var line = find (state.accounts, {id:id})
  console.log(line)
}
</script>
```

```js
// child component
<template>
 <div v-for="line in lines" :key="line.id">
    <span @click="goaway(line.id)" >X</span>
    {{ line.foo) }}
    {{ line.bar}}
  </div>
</template>
<script setup>
const props = defineProps({ 'lines': Array)}
const emit = defineEmits(['goaway'])
const goaway = (id) => emit('goaway', id)

</script>
```

Upon page load, I get this message in the console: *Extraneous non-emits event listeners (goaway(id)) were passed to component but could not be automatically inherited because component renders fragment or text root nodes. If the listener is intended to be a component custom event listener only, declare it using the "emits" option.*

I understand the *"emits" option* to be `defineProps`. But I must be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is: you should use `@goaway`, but not `@goaway(id)`.

Part of template:

```
<template>
<!--- THIS IS WRONG, SEE UPDATE BELOW -->
  <TheAccountLines :lines="recurrents_credits" @goaway(id)="goaway(id)" />
</template>
```

BTW, you can use `onGoaway` prop instand `@goaway`:

```
// parent component
<template>
  <TheAccountLines :lines="recurrents_credits" @goaway="goaway" />
</template>

// child component
<script setup>
const props = defineProps(['onGoaway'])

const emitDelete = (id) => { props.goaway(id) }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Like always, after hours of searching, I find the answer 5 minutes after asking the question here. I will not delete the question (unless moderation prefers I do that).

The error was in the parent : don't use the parameters in the emit :

[documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#event-arguments)

```
<TheAccountLines :lines=recurrents_credits @goaway="goaway" />
```